# What are the different languages represented in Acts 2:9-11a?

Tags: acts

v9 Parthians and Medes and Elamites and those dwelling in Mesopotamia, both in Judea and Cappadocia, in Pontus and Asia,
v10 Both in Phrygia and Pamphylia, in Egypt and the parts of Libya around Cyrene, and the sojourning of Rome, both Jews and proselytes,
v11a Cretans and Arabians,

Peoples - Parthians, Medes, Elamites, Cretans, Arabians
Regions - Mesopotamia, Judea, Cappadocia, Pontus, Asia, Phrygia, Pamphylia, Egypt, Libya, Cyrene, Rome,

Here is a map of the places:
[image: Acts 2 map]

Comment: There is a direct connection to Isaiah’s prophecy *“and I will **set a sign** among them. And from them I will send survivors (saved people are survivors, Christians are said to be saved) to the nations, **to Tarshish, Pul, and Lud, who draw the bow, to Tubal and Javan, to the coastlands far away**, that have not heard my fame or seen my glory. And they shall declare my glory among the nations.”
‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭66:19‬*

Answer (score 1):

Roman Latin would have been the primary language alongside Greek and Hebrew/aramaic.

Parthian kingdom (central Asia) spoke Parthian a north western Iranian language.

Medes (Armenia) spoke according to http://farsibg.com/library/languageofmedians.pdf median, an indo-European language.

Elamites spoke Elamite according to https://www.historytoday.com/archive/puzzle-proto-elamite. Here's a excerpt which is rather interesting:

> "Some linguists believe Elamite to be related to the Dravidian
> languages of South India, which include Tamil, and an Elamo-Dravidian
> family stretching from the Gulf to India could include the language of
> the Harappan civilisation in the Indus Valley. Interestingly enough,
> proto-Elamite tablets have been discovered at sites far eastwards
> towards Baluchistan, though a few hundred tablets and fragments have
> recently been unearthed near Tehran, so it seems the language was
> probably spoken over a wide area of Iran. Could the tablets represent
> an early version of Elamite? If so why did the writing rapidly die
> out? These tablets date to the period around 3200 to 2900 BC, but Dahl
> believes that those discovered to date represent only a very short
> period, possibly no more than a few scribal generations. Precise
> dating is difficult because of uncertainty in carbon dates at around
> that time, due to a plateau in the carbon curve for that period."

Cretans spoke a Greek dialect known as Cretan.

Arabians would have spoken Persian.

I think generally there would have been a lot of languages spoken at the time as it was the feast of Pentecost and Jews from the diaspora would have been there.

Where Babel was the dividing of one language into many, Pentecost was the bringing together of one language heard as many.